# Index is stable under finite rank perturbations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose that $f: V \rightarrow W$ is Fredholm and $g: V \rightarrow W$ has finite rank. Then $f +g$ is Fredholm and $ind(g + f) = ind(f)$.

Notation:
Fredholm maps are those with kernel and cokernel finite dimensional.
Also, index of a linear map $f$ is $ind(f) = dimker(f) - dimcoker(f)$.

Comment: That is the second question about Fredholm operators that you ask in a very short time period. Both without any attempts from your side. What are they?

Comment: Just some interest of mine, I was actually asking for these questions to try to know how to proof this kinds of statements, I was so unfamiliar with them at first. The topic is part of my second course in Linear Algebra, but all sources I found were using concepts I couldn't understand.

Comment: If it's part of a course, why don't they prove the theorems?

Comment: What do you mean by not proving the theorems? This is just an exercise, like an application in Linear Algebra. Not a course in operator theory.

Comment: Well, ok. This one here is not so hard. The other one with the index theorem is (and should, in my eyes, not be given as an exercise).

Answer (score 1):

More generally, $f+g$ is Fredholm for any compact operator $g$. Once you know this and the fact that the index is continuous, you know that $$\mathrm{ind}(f + tg), \; t \in \mathbb{R}$$ is a continuous, integer-valued function and therefore constant.

Comment: So, he/she has to know two things one of which is not at all trivial...

Comment: Proving that the index is continuous is nontrivial but maybe OP already knows this result